# How to insert objects from a list in drools rule?

Tags: drools

I want to insert a list of objects in the then part dynamically when this rule is included for run.

```
rule "insert adresses"
  when
  $person:Person(state=="DC")
   then
       //insert all address of this person, person.getAddresses() return a set of Address
```

Answer (score 5):

2 possible ways:

```
rule "insert adresses"
when
  $person: Person(state=="DC")
  $a: Address() from $person.getAddresses()
then
  insert($a);
end
```

and

```
rule "insert adresses"
when
  $person: Person(state=="DC")
then
  for (Address a : $person.getAddresses()){
    insert(a);
  }
end
```

Both rules have the same result. Maybe option number one is better if you want to add some filter to the addresses you want to insert.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

In fact I think that there are some differences. In option 1 there will be one activation and fire per Address. In option 2 you will have just one activation and fire per person. 
It is true that with the second option you cannot filter the Addresses in a nice way, but you will definitely reduce the firings. It all depends on what do you want to do with the addresses and if you care about the firings or not.

Comment: Interesting. Any idea which will cost more? is rule firing costly? btw, thanks for the example